# Silverlight ListBox control doesn't rebind correctly

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, listbox

I'm using a ListBox control with an ItemTemplate like so:

```
<ListBox Name="lbItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text=" - " Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then, in the code I dynamically bind a collection to the ListBox like so:

```
lbItemssList.ItemsSource = _itemsList.Values;
```

But at times I need to rebind a different or modified list of items to the ListBox.  When I do this, the ListBox doesn't update with the new list and it seems that the binding doesn't work correctly, unless I do this:

```
lbItemssList.ItemsSource = null;
lbItemssList.ItemsSource = _itemsList.Values;
```

I've done the same thing with other ListBox controls and not had this problem.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no "bind" here, you have simply assigned a collection to the `ItemsSource` property.

The `ItemsSource` property will compare the value assigned to it with the current value, if the value is the same it will do nothing.

My guess is your `Values` property is not a `ObservableCollection` (in which case the ListBox would track collection changes without you having to anything).  Also whilst you may have changed the content of the `Values` collection it remains the same instance of the collection originally assigned to the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: There's a bind in the xaml (to the current DataContext) but then it's overwritten in the code-behind :)

Comment: Aaahh - so it just looks at whether it's a different instance or not rather than whether the collection is any different.  I see.  That answers it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have tired that at my side and its working fine. 
My Code

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindData();
    }

private void BindData()
    {
        List<MyClass> listClass = new List<MyClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            MyClass aMyClass = new MyClass();
            aMyClass.Description = "Description  " + i.ToString();
            aMyClass.ID = i;
            listClass.Add(aMyClass);
        }

        lbItemsList.ItemsSource = listClass;
    }

private void buttonaa_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyClass> listClass = new List<MyClass>();
        for (int i = 20; i < 40; i++)
        {
            MyClass aMyClass = new MyClass();
            aMyClass.Description = "Description  " + i.ToString();
            aMyClass.ID = i;
            listClass.Add(aMyClass);
        }
        lbItemsList.ItemsSource = null;
        lbItemsList.ItemsSource = listClass;
    }



 <ListBox Name="lbItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Padding="5,0,0,0" />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Do check if you are geting the same recored from databse and you are thinking that list is no refreshing

Comment: I think @Zannjaminderson is asking why the initial assignment of `null` is necessary to make it work.  In your case you could remove the `null` assignment and it would still work.  See may answer for an explaination.